# redirecting result of running assembly code in linux to text file

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, printf, io-redirection

I'm trying to write a Python script to test the output of some various code I've written in assembly against an expected output. However I am having difficulty redirecting the output into a file.
I have written the following:

```
extern printf
LINUX   equ     80H     ; interupt number for entering Linux kernel
EXIT    equ     1       ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()
section .data
    intfmt: db "%ld", 10, 0

segment .text
    global  main


main:
    push rax
    push rsi
    push rdi
    mov rsi, 10
    mov rdi, intfmt
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop rax 
    call os_return      ; return to operating system


os_return:
    mov  rax, EXIT      ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()
    mov  rbx, 0     ; Error code 0 i.e. no errors
    mov rcx, 5
    int  LINUX      ; Interrupt Linux kernel
```

I then procede to do the following in the console:

```
nasm -f elf64 basic.asm
gcc -m64 -o basic basic.o
./basic
```

Which outputs 10 to the screen.
However if I enter

```
./basic > basic.txt
cat basic.txt
```

basic.txt appears as an empty file.
My overall goal is to write a shell script that loops over each assembly file to compiling and run the file and then redirect the output of this script into a file. However I cannot do this until I can get it to work with a single file.
I was wondering it it was something to do with my call to printf? Although I was under the illusion that printf writes to STDOUT.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're redirecting input properly on the console. Have you checked that the assembly prints to std out?

Comment: What do you see on the screen if you run `./basic | cat` ?

Comment: John - ./basic | cat still returns nothing
Jex - I looked up the printf documentation and it says it prints to stdout.

Comment: Related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) - don't do that.  Also, if you use stdio functions like printf, call `exit(3)` or return from main, instead of making a raw `_exit(2)` system call that doesn't check if stdio buffers need flushing first.  [Using printf in assembly leads to an empty ouput](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38379553).  That's the reason your redirect fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your redirection is correct; the problem must be in the assembly you are generating.

*The* tool to debug such problems is `strace`. Running your program under `strace`, shows:

```
strace ./basic
...
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa5bb8da000
write(1, "10\n", 3)                     = 3
10
write(1, "z\377n\f\377\177\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\202\377n\f\377\177\0\0\362\377n\f\377\177\0\0"..., 139905561665008 <unfinished ... exit status 0>
```

You can clearly see your desired output, but also some "stray" write. Where is that write coming from?

GDB to the rescue:

```
gdb  -q ./basic
Reading symbols from /tmp/basic...done.

(gdb) catch syscall write
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'write' [1])
(gdb) r

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall 'write'), 0x00007ffff7b32500 in __write_nocancel ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b32500 in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00007ffff7acd133 in _IO_new_file_write (f=0x7ffff7dd7780, data=0x7ffff7ff8000, n=3) at fileops.c:1276
#2  0x00007ffff7ace785 in new_do_write (fp=0x7ffff7dd7780, data=0x7ffff7ff8000 "10\n", to_do=3) at fileops.c:530
#3  _IO_new_do_write (fp=0x7ffff7dd7780, data=0x7ffff7ff8000 "10\n", to_do=3) at fileops.c:503
#4  0x00007ffff7accd9e in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7dd7780, data=0x601023, n=1) at fileops.c:1358
#5  0x00007ffff7a9f9c8 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd7780, format=<value optimized out>, ap=0x7fffffffda20) at vfprintf.c:1644
#6  0x00007ffff7aaa53a in __printf (format=0x7ffff7ff8000 "10\n") at printf.c:35
#7  0x000000000040054f in main ()
```

Good, this is the expected call to write.

```
(gdb) c
10

Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall 'write'), 0x00007ffff7b32500 in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
```

This is just the return from syscall. Did write succeed? (We know it did, since we see its output above, but let's confirm.)

```
(gdb) p $rax
$1 = 3
```

Good. Write wrote the expected 3 characters.

```
(gdb) c

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall 'write'), 0x0000000000400577 in os_return ()
```

This is the write we didn't expect. Where from?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400577 in os_return ()
#1  0x0000000000400557 in main ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function os_return:
   0x0000000000400557 <+0>: movabs $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000400561 <+10>:    movabs $0x0,%rbx
   0x000000000040056b <+20>:    movabs $0x5,%rcx
   0x0000000000400575 <+30>:    int    $0x80
=> 0x0000000000400577 <+32>:    nop
   0x0000000000400578 <+33>:    nop
   0x0000000000400579 <+34>:    nop
   0x000000000040057a <+35>:    nop
   0x000000000040057b <+36>:    nop
   0x000000000040057c <+37>:    nop
   0x000000000040057d <+38>:    nop
   0x000000000040057e <+39>:    nop
   0x000000000040057f <+40>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) quit
```

So your syscall executed `write(2)` instead of expected `exit(2)`. Why did this happen?

Because you've defined `EXIT` incorrectly:

```
grep 'define .*NR_exit' /usr/include/asm/unistd*.h
/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h:#define __NR_exit                1
/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h:#define __NR_exit_group          252
/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h:#define __NR_exit                60
/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h:#define __NR_exit_group          231
```

From above, you can tell that `EXIT` should be 1 in 32-bit mode, but 60 in 64-bit mode.

What about NR_write? Is it 1 in 64-bit mode?

```
grep 'define .*NR_write' /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h 
#define __NR_write              1
#define __NR_writev             20
```

Indeed it is. So we have solved the "where did stray write come from?" puzzle. Fixing `EXIT` to be 60, and rerunning under `strace`, we now see:

```
...
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa5bb8da000
write(1, "10\n", 3)                     = 3
10
_exit(1)                                = ?
```

That still isn't right. We should be calling `_exit(0)`, not `_exit(1)`. A look at the `x86_64` [ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64), reveals that your register use is incorrect: syscall number should be in `%rax`, but the arguments in `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, etc.

Fixing that (and deleting bogus `mov rcx, 5`), we finally get desired output from `strace`:

```
...
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa5bb8da000
write(1, "10\n", 3)                     = 3
10
_exit(0)                                = ?
```

So *now* we are ready to see if above fixes also fixed the redirection problem.

Re-running under strace, with output redirected:

```
strace ./basic > t
...
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08161eb000
_exit(0)                                = ?
```

Clearly our call to `write` is missing. Where did it go?

Well, `stdout` output is line buffered by default, and gets fully buffered when redirected to a file. Perhaps we are missing an `fflush` call?

Indeed, adding a call to `fflush(NULL)` just before exiting solves the problem:

```
...
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8afd450000
write(1, "10\n", 3)                     = 3
_exit(0)                                = ?
```

I hope you've learned something today (I did ;-)

Comment: No, the code the question does call exit using the 32 bit interface, which confuses strace when run in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Your answer is assuming that `strace` decodes `int 0x80` system calls from 64-bit code correctly.  It [didn't](https://superuser.com/questions/834122/) (or didn't used to; with better kernel support it finally does in the last half a year or so).   There is no stray `write()` system call, that's just how `strace` mis-decodes `exit`.  The *only* real problem is failure to fflush, or `call exit` or return from main.  Using the int 0x80 ABI is generally a bad idea, but is not the direct cause of the problem.  Your intermediate steps towards your final fix actually introduce new bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting from main by

```
mov rax, 0; exit code
ret
```

Comment: Yes, this works (because it results in flushing stdio buffers before exit), but your answer should explain *why*.